# Laravel 5.5 validation if checkbox is check and then validation on some field

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am new in Laravel I want to need some validation if I checked checkbox then in front of input field will validate Required|Numeric|min:1

Please Help.

As per below image[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `required_if`.

So, you could have the following rules in your [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation) or your [Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators).

```
return [
    'systolic_blood_pressure_high' => 'nullable|numeric|min:1|required_if:has_systolic_bp,on',
    'systolic_blood_pressure_low'  => 'nullable|numeric|min:1|required_if:has_systolic_bp,on',
];
```

Assuming you have a checkbox with name `has_systolic_bp` and it is checked, the fields `systolic_blood_pressure_high` and `systolic_blood_pressure_low` will be required.

You also need to mark them as `nullable` as by default Laravel will consider them as invalid because of the `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middlewares.

For more information, check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)